# Jquery widget undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widget-factory

First, I am using an MVC WebAPI project. My scripts are configured in the bundle config and then rendered on the page (Index.cshtml).I am trying to create a JQuery widget using the widget factory. I have created the 'test' javascript file with this content:

```
$.widget("custom.test", {
    options: {
        value: 0
    },
    _create: function () {
        this.options.value = this._constrain(this.options.value);
        this.element.addClass("test");
        this.refresh();
    },
    _setOption: function (key, value) {
        if (key === "value") {
            value = this._constrain(value);
        }
        this._super(key, value);
    },
    _setOptions: function (options) {
        this._super(options);
        this.refresh();
    },
    refresh: function () {
        var testVal = this.options.value + "%";
        this.element.text(testVal);
        if (this.options.value == 100) {
            this._trigger("complete", null, { value: 100 });
        }
    },
    _constrain: function (value) {
        if (value > 100) {
            value = 100;
        }
        if (value < 0) {
            value = 0;
        }
        return value;
    },
    _destroy: function () {
        this.element
            .removeClass("test")
            .text("");
    }
});
```

In the Index file I render the bundles:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
```

in the head of the file (NOTE: My widget script file is in the lib bundle). Then, after the rendering code, I added a script tag and added this:

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                //OTHER CODE

                var test = $("<div></div>")
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .test();

                test.option( "value", 50 );

                alert(test.options.value);
            });

        </script>
```

There is other code in the this script tag so I know at least some of the code works. Now, when I load the page I get an error (it directs me to the $.widget("custom.test", ...) portion of the code) saying *"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"*. I can see, when I look at the source, that the javascript files are being included in the correct order.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

There was a syntax issue with how I was attempting to access information from the widget. The proper code is:

```
            var something = $(".test").colorize();
            something.colorize("option", "value", 100);
            var test = something.colorize("option", "value");
            alert(test);

            something.colorize("random");
            alert(something.colorize("option", "red"));
```

Comment: Does it all work without bundling?

Comment: No it does not. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I would say then its got nothing to do with the bundling, and its an error in the code. Include the JS unbundled and unminified, and (assuming your using Visual Studio), use IE (must be IE) put a breakpoint in the create of your widget and step through the code until you get to the error. `undefined is not a function` will be the error from you trying to execute a method on an object that is null, just need to find which one... OR add some `alerts` or `console.log` to points in the code and find exactly where the error is occuring. Also VS will only debug JS in JS files, (i.e. not on the page)

Comment: There was indeed an error in the usage of the widget. I have learned how to properly use the widget and am editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concatenating javascript files, make sure they are ending with `(jQuery);` and not just `(jQuery)` - note the semicolon

If your bundled JS is not minified - the line number the uncaught typeerror cites should lead you to this.

(This is the case 99% of the time I see this and the developer is combining files - though it is not always the case)

Comment: I am not concatenating them. The bundles just write script tags in the HTML.

Comment: Does it give you a line number? Whats at that line number? Can you expand it for a stack trace?